# Editcap input/output files

Tags: bash, wireshark, packet-capture, editcap

I'm trying to run editcap on a bunch of files in different folders, and I have no problems doing it using *. 
For example:

```
editcap captures/*/*.gzip
```

The problem is that when I also try to specify an output file, for example with:

```
editcap captures/*/*.gz ./outputFile
```

the outputFile is read as part of the input and I don't get any output.

Someone knows how to solve that problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, and what I wrote is partially wrong. 
Editcap is able to deal only with 1 input file at the time, as you can see in it's synopsis here:
[editcap man page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html).